# What is the Dirichlet serie of The function $A$ (OEIS A001414) which gives the sum of prime factors (with repetition) of a number $n$?

Tags: number-theory, arithmetic-functions, dirichlet-series, mobius-function, dirichlet-convolution

The function $A$ (OEIS A001414) which gives the sum of prime factors (with repetition) of a number $n$ and defined by
$$
A(n)=\sum \limits_{p^{\alpha}\parallel n}\alpha p
$$
is this serie calculated before ? and where i can found the resources
$$
\sum \limits_{n\geq 1} \frac{A(n)}{n^s}
$$
and
$$
\sum \limits_{n\geq 1} \frac{\mu(n)A(n)}{n^s}
$$

Comment: thanks , please can you give me the resources for this serie , and i think for the second serie is -Pp(s)/ζ(s)

Comment: OEIS entry A001414 indicates "Dirichlet g.f. $f(s)*\zeta(s)$, where $f(s)=\sum\limits_{p\  prime} \frac{p}{p^s-1}=\sum\limits_{k>0} primezeta(k*s-1)$ is the Dirichlet g.f. for A120007. Totally additive with $a(p^e) = p*e$" where I've converted some of the formulas to MathJax. I'm not sure you're going to do much better.

Answer (score 0):

Unclear what you are asking for exactly.
With $P(s)=\sum_{p^k}p^{1-sk}=\sum_p \frac{p^{1-s}}{1-p^{-s}}$
$$\sum_{n\ge 1} n^{-s}\sum_{p^k| n} p = \zeta(s)P(s)$$

$$\sum_{n\ge 1} n^{-s}\mu(n)\sum_{p^k| n} p = 
\sum_{p^k} p \sum_{n\ge 1} (p^k n)^{-s}\mu(p^k n)$$ $$=-\sum_p p \sum_{n\ge 1,p\,\nmid \,n} (p n)^{-s}\mu(n) = -\sum_p p \frac{p^{-s}}{(1-p^{-s})\zeta(s)}= -\frac{P(s)}{\zeta(s)}$$

Comment: thank you Sir , please can you give me the References